# Why creating generic List not binding the right data type at runtime?

Tags: java, generics, collections

I am trying to create a generic method that returns a generic list with a given data type.

I have passed `Integer` as data type and I filled with `String` with no issue at runtime.

My question why I didn't receive `ClassCastException` during the Runtime?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = (List<Integer>) generic(Integer.class);
        System.out.println(list);
    }

    private static <T> List<?> generic(T clazz) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add((T) Arrays.asList("create", "generic"));
        list.add((T) Arrays.asList("create", "generic2"));
        return list;
    }
```

, output

```
[[create, generic], [create, generic2]]
```

Comment: Something something [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), not every violation of the generic type system is identified at runtime. This situation is also called *heap pollution*. But you should have received “unchecked” warnings from the compiler.

But your assumption that you create a `List<Integer>` is wrong anyway. You are passing `Integer.class` as argument for the `T clazz` parameter, hence, `T` is not `Integer` but `Class<Integer>`.

A correct generic declaration would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = generic(Integer.class);
    System.out.println(list);
}

private static <T> List<T> generic(Class<T> clazz) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    return list;
}
```

Now that the program is free of “unchecked” warnings, you can be sure that no heap pollution will occur at runtime. If you want more guarantees, you can use

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = generic(Integer.class);
    System.out.println(list);
}

private static <T> List<T> generic(Class<T> clazz) {
    List<T> list = Collections.checkedList(new ArrayList<>(), clazz);
    list.add((T) Arrays.asList("create", "generic")); // will fail at runtime
    list.add((T) Arrays.asList("create", "generic2"));
    return list;
}
```

However, when you listen and respond to the compiler warnings, you don’t need the additional runtime checks.

Answer (score 0):

As you have declared `T` as `<T>` the runtime type-checking of `(T)` is against `Object`. Therefore, the cast from a `List` is fine.

`List` is declared as `List<E>`, so there can be no additional internal runtime type-checking from `List.add`. Likewise for `List.toString`.

You will, however, get warnings (so long as the lint option is enabled in your compiler). Don't ignore the warnings.

You can use `clazz.cast` in place of `T`, though `T` cannot usefully be a parameterised type.

Answer (score 0):

Generics provide type checks at **compile time** and are erased by the compiler during the [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genMethods.html). So after the type erasure your method will look something like this:

```
private static List generic(Object clazz) {
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add((Object) Arrays.asList("create", "generic"));
    list.add((Object) Arrays.asList("create", "generic2"));
    return list;
}
```

And your `main` method will look as follows:

```
List list = (List) generic(Integer.class);
System.out.println(list);
```

So there's no reason for a `ClassCastException` to be thrown, because you are not trying to do any `Integer` specific actions to the elements of your list. But you will get it as soon as you do, for example:

```
list.forEach(integer -> System.out.println(integer.intValue()));
```

because here it will try to cast `ArrayList` to `Integer` to call `intValue()`.

**Conclusion:** using generics along with unchecked casting is quite useless.